# Предлог "у" в предложении "Песня, мотив У которой..."

Tags: предлоги

Обычно говорят: "Песня, мотив которой", а допустим ли вариант: "Песня, мотив у которой", т.е. меня интересует, грамотно ли в данном случае использование предлога "у". Вопрос принципиальный, буду очень благодарна за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

Вполне. Если возможно сказать "мотив у песни", возможно и "мотив у которой":

Крис Кельми :

Свой мотив у каждой птицы,

свой мотив у каждой песни

Свой мотив у неба и земли.

Михаил Дудин: «Мотив у песни чист и прост...»   По-моему, М.Дудин - грамотный человек.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила!

Comment: "Песня, мотив у которой." Не могу придумать нормальный пример с таким порядком слов.  Если "свой мотив у каждой песни", то  "песня, у которой свой мотив", но не "песня, мотив у которой свой". И т.п.